# LSTM results seems to be shifted by one time period back

Tags: time-series, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

With LSTM and Keras I built a simple time series prediction model which works like this:
Providing that I have the data (normalized and prepared for training) for some past 10 time periods, the model predicts the values of the proceeding two time periods.

My Data is shaped similar to this:

X = [[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11],[3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]]]

Y = [[11,12],[12,13],[14,15]]

And the model is composed of one LSTM layer with rnn_size number of nodes
as well as one dropout layer.

```
    model = Sequential()

    model.add(LSTM(rnn_size,
    batch_input_shape=(batch_size, X.shape[1], 
    X.shape[2]),stateful=True,dropout=dropout))

    model.add(Dropout(dropout)) 
    model.add(Dense(y.shape[1]))
    adam_optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(clipvalue=5)
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=adam_optimizer)
    history = model.fit(X, y, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=nb_epoch, 
                    verbose=2, validation_split=0.1,shuffle=False)
    #################################    
    # Predict
    result = scaler.inverse_transform(
              model.predict_on_batch(test_values[start_date:end_date]
              .values.reshape(1, 1, -1)))
```

The problem is that the predicted value for time period t+1 - as can be seen in the graph - seems to be somehow just a slightly different value from the one at the time period t.

Is this a (normal) behaviour?
If not, how can I overcome it?

I think I have a relatively good understanding of how LSTM work, however I could not wrap my head around this particular issue.

### Edit 1:

I edited the code to use stateless network configurations and edited the shape as suggested by Daniel. However the problem persist.
Strangely also, the validation loss (MSE) is always lower than the training loss.

### Edit 2:

Rest of the code added as per [Marcin's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5974433/marcin-mo%C5%BCejko) request

[actual value vs. predicted value for the test data set that was not shown to the model before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGzbu.png)

[Validation Loss is less than Training Loss! ( small fluctuation is because of Dropout )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdkUC.png)

Comment: Use `stateful=False` and check if it solves the problem. (`True` is only for cases where you divide "a single" sequence in many batches, being each batch the exact sequel of the previous one)

Comment: Could you provide a rest of the code?

Comment: Hey Marcin, you could see the rest of the code above.

Answer (score 0):

For the LSMT to understand the sequences, it must have input shapes like `(batch,timeSteps,featuresPerStep)`

So, `X.shape` must be `(batch,10,1)`:

```
[[[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10]],
 [[2],[3],...........................,[11]],
 [........................................]]
```

For creating the LSTM layers, you don't need to pass the batch size if you're not using `stateful=True` (only use this option if the sequences in the second bach are sequels of the sequences in the first batch). For this sliding window case, you can't mend sequences together. Each sequence is individual.

```
LSTM(rnn_size,input_shape=(X.shape[1],X.shape[2]))
```

These two changes (X shape and stateful) may change significantly your results.

Comment: :) -- If after testing you conclude this answers your question properly, please mark it as answered.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply!
I posted an edit to the question after applying the modifications you suggested.